# Google Maps SDK didChangeCameraPosition() gets called repeatedly

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xcode7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to refresh my Google map by fetching new, different sets of data from a different geohash region whenever a user moves/scrolls the camera to a another location in the map.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        if let curLocation = curLocation{
            loadDataFromFireBase(curLocation.coordinate)
        }
}
```

However, for some reasons this function gets called repeatedly every single second even if I haven't moved the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this. Instead of using `didChangeCameraPosition` you can use `idleAtCameraPosition`.

Comment: would have been more constructive!